# python upload data, not file, to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I know how to upload a file to s3 buckets in Python. I am looking for a way to upload data to a file in s3 bucket directly. In this way, I do not need to save my data to a local file, and then upload the file. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, most issues I see on StackOverflow is when people try to do it this way. It is normally much safer to `upload_file()` rather than send data to a file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I do not find any way to to it yet

Comment: @John Rotenstein. Do you know why uploading a file is safer?

Comment: I think people make more mistakes where code is more complex. It is simpler to write code that creates a file, then uploads a file. When people try to do both in the same step, they run into more problems. It is also easier to test code that does it in separate steps. However, @CharlesLandau's method will probably work (note that it uses the Resource method instead of the Client method).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am editing to include client method, I thought it would be fine to just point out one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK standard `Object.put()` supports this.

```
resp = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key/key.txt').put(Body=b'data')
```

Edit: it was pointed out that you might want the client method, which is just `put_object` with the kwargs differently organized

```
client.put_object(Body=b'data', Bucket='bucket_name', Key='key/key.txt')
```